# How to localize the pivot headers into other languages

Tags: windows-phone-7

Textblock's content is easy to be localized into other langauges. However, I could not figure out how to localize the pivot header into other languages. Below is the pivot, I need to localize the pivot header. example header ="String in other languages" Would appreciate your help on this.

```
<controls:Pivot Name="Pivot1" Title="MyPivotDemo" >


        <controls:PivotItem Header="first" >

        </controls:PivotItem >

        <controls:PivotItem Header="second" >

        </controls:PivotItem >

    </controls:Pivot >
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pivot headers can be localized by using binding the Title property with the Resource string
as follows

```
<controls:Pivot Name="Pivot" Title="{Binding ResourceContainer.PIVOT_TITLE, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FontSize="23">

<controls:PivotItem>
</controls:PivotItem>

</controls:Pivot>
```

please try by creating static resource localizedstrings and also add resources in .resx files for different languages.

for details refer http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/09/localization-and-globalization-in-wp7.html

and MSDN globalization or localization for windows phone 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637522%28v=vs.92%29.aspx